# Listen to queue on Mule, process the informtion and senf back

Tags: spring, mule, message-queue

I build spring application and send to RabbitMQ.
now I want to build project in Mule ESB that listen to queue and work with the information, if has variable a (for example) -> process to aa flow etc..., -> convert responses to JSON -> send back to RabbitMQ. -

1) It will need to be RabbitMQ or other it possible?
2) How to do that   - listen to specific queue and process it?
3) And after, how to send back?

I saw some examples but didn't understand the topic perfect.

`*
     
         
    </amqp:queue-profile> -->

```
 <flow name="amqpChoiceAckNackService">
  <amqp:inbound-endpoint queueName="my-queue"
                         connector-ref="amqpManualAckLocalhostConnector" />

    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="8080" path="message" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="#[message.inboundProperties['msg']]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>        
        <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
            <amqp:outbound-endpoint queueName="test.queue1" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="AMQP1" connector-ref="AMQP_Connector1"/>
            <custom-processor class="CustomProcessor" doc:name="Custom Processor"/>
       </processor-chain>       
</flow>*`
```

Who can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: In addition: How to run the Mule application, and be sure that performed OK?

Answer (score 0):

to listen to a queue in mule you need to have following configuration,(I am not familiar to amqp but this way also works)

```
<spring:bean id="rabbitMQconnectionFactory" class="RabbitMQconnectionFactoryClass"> 
    <!--..whatever properties are required by this class (hint :- search how to make a rabbitMQ connection factory bean) -->
</spring:bean>
<jms:connector name="rabbitMQconnector" connectionFactory-ref="rabbitMQconnectionFactory" username="" password="" doc:name="JMS"/>
<flow name="flow1" doc:name="Flow1">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="rabbitMQconnector" queue="queueNameToListen"/>
</flow>
```

to verify if the code worked , put a message on the queue you want to listen and run the mule application, if that message gets consumed properly you will see the message as dequed and no pending messages.

hope this helps!

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided in your question will work just fine. You just need to add `exchangeType="topic"` to the endpoint component.

More info available in the AMQP connector guide below:
https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-transport-amqp/blob/master/GUIDE.md

Example flow:

```
<amqp:connector name="amqpConnector" host="${host}" port="${port}" username="${username}" password="${password}"/>
<amqp:endpoint name="myExchange" exchangeName="${exchangeName}" queueName="${topicName}" exchangeType="topic" exchangeAutoDelete="false" exchangeDurable="true" queueAutoDelete="false" queueDurable="true"connector-ref="amqpConnector"/>
<flow name="main">
    <amqps:inbound-endpoint ref="myExchange"/>
    <flow-ref name="doSomething"/>
    <amqp:outbound-endpoint ref="myExchange"/>
</flow>
```